# Ubuntu 20.04 becomes unresponsive/laggy

Tags: nvidia, 20.04

I have noticed that after some time after i boot into the system, the system becomes
less responsive, so if i for example click on Wifi at the top bar, i don't instantly get the pop up, also some windows are not opening instantly.

If i try to run lets say Witcher 3, the game also has less performance, so i have to reboot my computer.

I have set my GPU to "prefer maximum performance".

Anything i could try ? Thanks

```
System:
  Host: lnx-pc Kernel: 5.4.0-29-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX Z390-E GAMING v: Rev 1.xx 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1302 
  date: 09/02/2019 
CPU:
  6-Core: Intel Core i5-9600K type: MCP speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4600 MHz 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] driver: nvidia 
  v: 440.64 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.64 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] driver: iwlwifi 
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I219-V driver: e1000e 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.86 TiB used: 460.71 GiB (24.1%) 
Info:
  Processes: 332 Uptime: 20m Memory: 31.28 GiB used: 3.03 GiB (9.7%) 
  Shell: zsh inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: I noticed something similar, but I am using nvidia-340 driver which received its probably final update recently. `top` tells there is pretty much CPU usage by Xorg often.